# Regex for find and replace of a substring in Python

Tags: python, pandas, regex

Fairly new to regular expressions and need someone to point me in the right direction. I am writing a program in Python that finds a substring from specified user input and replaces ONLY that substring with another string that has been specified by the user. I'm using pandas for manipulation of excel files and python's `re` module that has similar matching to Perl.

I'm dealing with files that look something like this:

| Site | Service | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 Cook Street |
| 2 | 3 | 101 Cook ave |
| 3 | 1 | 102 Cook Dr |
| 4 | 1 | 103 Cook Court |
| 5 | 2 | 104 Cook cir |
| 6 | 2 | 105 Cook drive |

In the address column, the values should be standardized to 100 COOK ST, 101 COOK AVE, 102 COOK DR, 103 COOK CT, etc. Each street type (street, avenue, drive) should be abbreviated.

Here is my code for the reformat function:

```
def reformat(find, format_to):

    count = 0

    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        cell_value = df.at[i, column_header]
        #update find with regex expression
        #try an exp that will partition string and match substring at end of string
        if cell_value == re.search(r'\w+$', find):
            cell_value = str(re.search(format_to)
            count += 1
        else:
            print("No matches found...\nReturning to search...")
            __main__()
        df.at[i, column_header] = cell_value
```

The variables `find` and `format_to` are from user input (in first provided example, st/str/stree/etc. would be `find` and ST would be `format_to`).

I'm having trouble finding a working regex that matches only the street type (st, rd, ave, etc.) and replaces only the matched substring with `format_to`. `r'\w+$'` won't identify any substrings I've thrown at it. I also need a regex for the initial assignment of `cell_value` and assignment of the updated value to `cell_value`, but haven't found anything that would work. I'm assuming the regex in initialization might be the same as the one in the boolean statement.

I've consulted Python's re documentation and Overflow's Regex Wiki, but haven't found anything that seems like it would work. However, this could be due to lack of understanding/experience.

Comment: You probably shouldn't loop over the cells, nor loop over the find/fomat_to. Why not use a dictionary of find/format_to, craft a regex automatically and replace **once**? Maybe provide a full reproducible example and some patterns to replace to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @mozway The dictionary approach sounds like a better idea. Apologies if this is a dumb question, but what is meant by automatically crafting a regex? Also, I have updated the question to better outline what I want to do.

Comment: You can use `pd.Series.str.replace` which accepts a regex. You can chain these replace calls if you have many.

Comment: I provided an example below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a dictionary of words to replace and craft a regex, then pass it to [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and use the dictionary to map the substitution:

```
import re

dic = {'STREET': 'ST', 'AVENUE': 'AVE', 'COURT': 'CT', 'DRIVE': 'DR'}

# craft the regex by combining all words
# word boundary (\b) on the left, string end ($) on the right
pattern = fr"\b({'|'.join(map(re.escape, dic))})$"
# '\\b(STREET|AVENUE|COURT|DRIVE)$'

df['out'] = (df['Address'].str.upper()
             .str.replace(pattern, lambda m: dic.get(m.group()), regex=True)
            )
```

Output:

```
   Site  Service          Address           out
0     1        1  100 Cook Street   100 COOK ST
1     2        3     101 Cook ave  101 COOK AVE
2     3        1      102 Cook Dr   102 COOK DR
3     4        1   103 Cook Court   103 COOK CT
4     5        2     104 Cook cir  104 COOK CIR
5     6        2   105 Cook drive   105 COOK DR
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XkFb3N/1)

Comment: Initially this wouldn't return the abbreviated versions of the suffixes, but I've altered it slightly and it worked for me. I used:
pattern = fr"\b({'|'.join(map(re.escape, dic.keys()))})$"
This properly created the list of suffixes (\b(STREET|AVENUE|etc.) for use with replace(). I appreciate the help.

Comment: @sweeney it's my mistake, I added the `re.escape` in the end (not really needed in your case but better practice to generalize) and placed it in the wrong spot, see update ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand how `find` is formated, but if it is the string `"st/str/stree"`, this might do the trick:

```
reg = rf"({'|'.join(find.split('/'))})$"
if re.search(reg, cell_value) is not None:
     cell_value = re.sub(reg, format_to, cell_value)
     count += 1
```

The regex that is created `reg = r'(st|str|stree)$'` matches one of the `st`, `str`, etc. and then the end of the string with `$`.